# Openlayers Very Slow to Load WFS Layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, openlayers, geoserver

I've been testing speeds for my WFS layer :

One way of doing it (the openlayers way)

```
station_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    'Active Stations',
    {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        format: "GeoJSON",
        protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS(
        {
            srsName : "EPSG:900913",
            url: "NOT REALLY EMPTY",
            featureNS : "NOT REALLY EMPTY",
            featurePrefix: "NOT REALLY EMPTY",
            featureType : "NOT REALLY EMPTY",
            outputFormat: "json",
            readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(),
        }),
    }
);

map.addLayers([google_hybrid, google_physical, google_satellite, station_layer]);
```

The loading time is tremendous

**Waiting : 3.73 s**

**Receiving : 2.66 s**

Or we can do it manually add it to features object

```
    var url = geo_url +"/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=LAYER&outputFormat=json";
    station_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Stations");

    var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
        'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
        'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + '?task=proxy',
        data:
        {
          url: url,
          json: true
        },
    }).done(function(results)
    {
        var gformat = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
        map.addLayer(station_layer);
        station_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(results));
    });
}
```

The loading time is much better

**Waiting : 325 ms**

**Receiving : 1.02 s**

They both return the exact same feature collection!

Now am I using the openlayers API wrong, or is it that openlayers coding is just slower for what im doing?

Comment: Use your browsers developertools and see where the time is spent. Could be that OpenLayers adds some more meta that you don't see that makes the server rerender in a slower way.